# Check if a text array contains one or more parameters

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a column of type text[] in that column looks like this

[Example Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIoOo.png)

I want to return any row that contains one or more of the passed parameters but i am not able to do this

I have tried

```
securitygroups: { [Op.contains]: ["blah-house","admin"] }
```

this only returns me the first row and not the second even though admin is in both row

i can loop through each of the parameters but that requires multiple database query's

Any suggestions on how to do this by passing multiple parameters

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using op.overlap

```
{ securitygroups: { [Op.overlap]: ["blah-house","admin"] } }
```